# php files being downloaded instead of rendered in browser over ssl

Tags: php, apache, https

having an issue with my php/apache config.  Files will render fine over http.  Over https, however, files are prompted for download/saving.  Weird thing is that images are rendering over https.

SSL Config tested as installed correctly on several sites.  Also, should be noted that this is in a plesk environment, but I am installing via shell access.

Virtual Host section is below:

```
 AddType text/html .php 
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

   ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/smartsites_error_log

   CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/smartsites_access_log common

ServerName secure.cognitionsmartsites.com

     <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs">
    Allow from all
            Options +Indexes
</Directory>

    IndexOptions
ServerAlias  secure.cognitionsmartsites.com

#UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs

#ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/vhosts/default/cgi-bin/"

SSLEngine On

#SSLVerifyClient none
#SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-L6E8a0

    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/intermediate.crt
```

Comment: Try changing the `AddType` on line 2 to `AddHandler`. Does that work?

Comment: I think that got it!!  you are the man...

Comment: actually..may not have worked as I thought

Comment: weird thing now is that the page is rendering in browser, but php code is being show as text (not processed)...any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not apache whiz, but I once had this problem, and while I don't remember the cause, I remember the process by which I found it: I just went through carefully comparing line by line the VirtualHost that I was using for handling HTTPS requests with the one I was using for HTTP requests. If you haven't already, do likewise. Any differences you find that aren't directly related to SSL and which you haven't for some reason explicitly decided you want are probably undesirable, and possibly the cause of your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `AddType` on line 2 to `AddHandler`. This will tell php to process your .php files instead of just setting the mimetype like `AddType` does.

Also, make sure you are starting your php code with `<?php` and not just `<?`.